# RTSP stream doesn't work on python, But does on VLC. why?

Tags: python, opencv, debugging, rtsp, ip-camera

I am trying to get my PTZ camera to stream using python 3 and openCV.
The URL i use in the code works with VLC stream but not with the code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src="rtsp://USER:PASS@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX/Streaming/Channels/101/")
FRAME_WIDTH = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
FRAME_HIGTH = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
print('Frame Size: ', FRAME_WIDTH, 'x', FRAME_HIGTH)

if cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
else:
    ret = False

while ret:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Camera', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run it i get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/.../CameraTest/TEST.py", line 4, in <module>
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src="rtsp://.../Streaming/Channels/101/") TypeError: Required argument 'index' (pos 1) not found
```

this is and HIKVISON PTZ camera.
Can I please get any tips for how to get her to stream.

TNX in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one small change, remove **src=** from the cv2.VideoCapture() method.
It should look like,

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://USER:PASS@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX/Streaming/Channels/101/")
```

Comment: wow! it worked! that is so weird because when i used other IP cameras for the same code it worked fine... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in Hikvision camera. Avoid using special letter in the password.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://username:password@10.199.27.123:554')
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video output', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)& 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```